# JSXGraph Zoom property

Tags: javascript, plugins, svg

Im having an issue with implementing [JSXGraph](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/) and their zoom feature. Currently I set it to false however it compresses the line and hardly displays anything. I'm not sure if this is a bug of the plugin or if I am just not implementing it correctly.
Here is what it should look like, but without including the property of

```
zoom:false
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UBs8j/

And here is was it looks like when I use the zoom property:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Bg9C/

I'm not very familiar with SVG's so I'm not sure what exactly is wrong here. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The zoom property is not of type boolean. Instead it consists of several sub-properties

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {
     boundingbox:[-6,2,6,-2], 
     showNavigation: true,  
     zoom: {
            factorX: 1.25,
            factorY: 1.25,
            wheel: false,
            needshift: false,
            eps: 0.1
        }
});
```

But it is available only in newer version of JSXGraph, so my suggestion is to use the latest version 0.99.1:

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsxgraph/0.99.1/jsxgraphcore.js
```

Comment: So you're my new favorite person and should probably introduce yourself as a hero to new people you meet. Just sayin.

Comment: Is there an official way to do this? I'm one of the main developers of JSXGraph.

Comment: Thanks for your work, this graph library is amazing!

Comment: You can go to the source code to see the options you have: https://github.com/jsxgraph/jsxgraph/blob/53dcec661e0fd819158c30e365a2058fc07ca8b9/src/options.js#L558